# Update Visual Studio from 2012 to 2017 makes application return error 404

Tags: .net, visual-studio, .net-4.0, visual-studio-2017, http-status-code-404

I work in an application using Visual Studio 2012, .Net Framework 4.0. Now, I need to update to VS 2017. The solution opens, builds and runs without errors.

When I access a public resource (i.e. Login.aspx, images), it loads successfully. After the login, the server always responds with an error 404. No matter if the resource requires authentication or not.

The exception is for the login page itself which never fails. After loading it, makes the other public resources also available (again).

Any idea for what might be the cause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The application has a custom login that creates the authentication ticket (.ASPXFORMSAUTH) with custom data in it. On following requests the data in the cookie is validated by a custom handler.

It also uses the System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login class, which creates the authentication ticket itself, without the custom data.

So, the browser was receiving two cookies with the same identifier and discarding one of them.

The VS 2012 wasn't loading the handler that validates the request. After migrating to VS 2017 (and IIS Express), the handler was loaded and the errors started.

The solution was to avoid sending the second, incomplete authentication ticket.